# Is it a better option to go for educational loan?

Tags: united-states, 401k, student-loan

After having few years of my career, I am going back to School as Part Time. I am contributing 20% of my income in the 401k ( My Employer doesn't participate).

My question is: Whether it is a good decision to cancel the 401k and make the college payment from the Pay Check (or) Keep the 401K AS IS, and take the Educational Loan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have four problems with student loan debt:

- It is not bankruptable.  The only way to get out of it is to die or become disabled. There are "forgiveness" programs, but most require you to work in public service or underprivileged sectors (that also pay less) for at least 5 years (usually 10).
- There's no collateral behind it.  With a car loan or mortgage there's something that you can "turn in" to satisfy most or all of the debt.  If you decide not to finish school (or have something happen that prevents you from finishing) you're stuck with the debt burden but don't have anything to "turn in" to cancel the debt.
- You don't "feel the pain" of debt until it's too late to turn back. You don't have the negative effects (payments, interest, etc.) until you're out of school (whether or not you complete your degree) and there's nothing you can do about it.
- It encourages you to spend more.  You are tempted to spend as much as you get approved for, which means new books, more classes, maybe some new school clothes, a meal plan, etc. Those things are not bad, but you might not buy them if you were spending cash. It "feels like" free money rather than debt.

Since you're not giving up a match, my advice would be to reduce your 401(k) as much as necessary and pay for school with cash.  While you *might* get a better return on your 401(k) that you pay in student loan interest, that money can't be touched until you retire, so the benefit will not be realized for many years.  You have plenty of time to make up that difference.

However - make sure that the degree you're pursuing will actually benefit your career.  You don't specify what career you're in or what degree you're pursuing, but in many fields a Master's degree doesn't actually help as much as experience. You can estimate the increase in income and compare that to the cost of the degree to see if it's actually worth it (or how long it takes to pay back the cost).

Comment: Thank you all. Over all feedback is to lower the 401K and pay the tuition fees. I might not go for Student Loan. This so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If it was me, I would slow down my contributions to the 401K and pay for school in cash.  In fact if income limits do not apply, I would not be using the 401K at all.

For school you don't know what negative things will happen.  You could be unable to finish for a variety of reason.  You might not be able to obtain an increase in income when you finish school.  Any negative situation will be made worse if you then have to pay off a student loan.  If you pay cash you can move on to the next thing in life.

If you do pay for school in cash, you will reduce or eliminate your contributions to your 401K.  The market is a fickle thing, and you may not achieve gains on the contributions and you could suffer losses.  Also people generally advocate investing in yourself about all other things.  Consider this a time to invest in you.

Given that your employer has no match you might be better off contributing some of the retirement money to a (ROTH) IRA that you control yourself.  You will have much more diverse set of investment options and for many providers (i.e. Vanguard or Fidelity) there is no fee.  Your employer 401K might have a fee.

Comment: Thank you all. Over all feedback is to lower the 401K and pay the tuition fees. I might not go for Student Loan. This so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a simplified scenario. Say that the educational loan has an interest rate equal to the returns that your 401k would get. In this case, it doesn't matter which one you do. If you pay the tuition directly you would have no extra retirement earnings but you would have no extra interest to pay. If you contributed  to the 401k and started paying loan interest, then the extra retirement earnings would cancel out the extra loan interest you're paying. Either way, you'd be paying  earning zero extra returns and paying zero extra interest.

It's not that simple, though, because your 401k return rate and the educational loan's interest rate will not match in reality; one will be higher. If the 401k's return rate is higher than the loan's interest rate, then it makes sense to take out the loan and continue contributing towards retirement. If the loan's interest rate is higher then it makes sense to stop pay tuition directly and skip out on the loan.

It's not that simple, though, because you can't completely predict what returns your 401k will yield. Taxes are also a confounding factor, since you can deduct contributions to a 401k and you can deduct interest paid towards the educational loan.

Some questions you need to ask yourself are: "Will my income increase once I graduate from school?", "How likely am I to complete a degree?", "Do I qualify for a government-subsidized loan?", and "What kind of yield can I expect from my 401k?".

Comment: Thank you all. Over all feedback is to lower the 401K and pay the tuition fees. I might not go for Student Loan. This so helpful.

Comment: Just got a question, If i took the educational loan .. whether the educational loan amount & interest would fall on any  Tax Deduction ??

Comment: Interest from an educational loan counts as an itemized deduction

Comment: So to be practical .. i will be paying only the actual loan amount. The Rate of interest which came on the loan amount will be in the itemized deduction. If thats the case, i can still keep my 401K and go for the educational loan

Comment: A tax deduction directly reduces the amount of income you pay tax on, which in turn reduces your taxes. So you will still pay some interest